# Incorrect must exist validation triggered after upgrading to rails 5.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I previously had my rails application using `5.0.1` and it was working great.  I upgraded to rails `5.1.1` and now I have a bunch of incorrect rails validations triggering with the message:

> - must exist

I found an article by BigBinary titled: [Rails 5 makes belongs_to association required by default](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html).  I figured it might be related to that. I attempted opting out of this default behavior by doing the following (as was suggested in the article):

```
# config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb

Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

After creating that file I stopped and restarted the server, but the issue persists.

Any ideas as to why these validations are triggering after upgrading from `5.0.1` to `5.1.1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  the `application.rb` file must be loaded in last, *after* initializer files because this is in there after upgrading to `rails 5.1.1`:

```
#config/application.rb
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module MyTestApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.load_defaults 5.1 # must be taking precedence over my opt-out config file.
  end
end
```

The solution was to remove that opt-out initializer file and after that `config.load_defaults 5.1` line to just add the opting-out line there:

```
#config/application.rb
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module MyTestApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.load_defaults 5.1
    Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false

  end
end
```